# Laravel: How to get CKEditor to display first few words of post body without altering the styling of other posts

Tags: php, html, laravel, ckeditor, laravel-blade

I am making a Laravel project which requires data written to and retrieved from the database using the CKEditor on my website. It displays the posts accordingly, so nothing wrong with the retrieval and I am able to trim each so the first few words show (because then I want people to click on the posts and read them on their individual pages) but the HTML from the CKEditor merges and edits the other posts which do not have any styling at all (which in this case is the strikethrough text).

[IMAGE 1: what happens to other posts thanks to post 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy8V9.png)

[IMAGE 2: what the other posts should look like because they have no styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awtl5.png)

[IMAGE 3: what post 4 fully says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfvWx.png)

All I'd really like is for the first words or even row of each post to show while retaining the format made from CKEditor (e.g. including italics and bold).

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks :)

**INDEX.BLADE.PHP**

```
@extends('layouts/app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    @if(count($posts)>0)
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <?php 
                $string = html_entity_decode($post->body);
            ?>
            <div class="well">
                <h3><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h3>
                <p>{!!Str::words($string, 7, '...')!!}</p>
                <small>{{$post->created_at}}</small>
            </div>
            <br/>
        @endforeach
        {{$posts->links()}}
    @else
        <h4>NO POSTS FOUND :(</h4>
    @endif
@endsection
```

Comment: Try this-


{{ Str::limit($post->body, 7) }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```php
{{ Str::limit($post->body, 7) }}
```

For CKEditor-

```php
{!! Str::limit($post->body, 7) !!}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that keeps the tags in and I don't want to see that hence why I used the {!! !!} to unescape the htmlentities. I want to see my text in the format, if that made sense. So for example post 4 has <strong> and <italics> tags right, I don't want to see the HTML tags for it, I want the text to display in **bold** and _in italics_ without it affecting the other posts because it seems to transfer the style onto the other posts.

Comment: `{!! Str::limit($post->body, 7) !!}` The `{!! !!}` used for escape HTML tags. This editor by default take `<p></p>` tag. if you use this it will remove all HTML tags.

Comment: True and then I'd be back where I started haha. So are you saying there's no real way for me to ideally get what I'm looking for?